# PayPal doesn't redirect back to customer page when paying through PayPal with a credit card in sandbox

Tags: paypal, payment, sandbox

i am using **Paypal buy now button** with **Sanbox seller account**. 
i have generated the button code and provide a **Return URL** of my web page but when i pay through **Don't have a PayPal account link** and follow all process to pay through Credit card.

During process i select **Continue to pay as a guest and not use my PayPal account** but after i click **Pay** button i am not redirected to my return URL provided page .

how to fix this :(:(

here is the button code:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="paypalForm">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="skariz_1316503728_biz@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="PSYC-OH-METER">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" >
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<a onclick="validateForm();" > <img alt=""
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" /></a>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is intended behaviour. You'll need to click the "Return to merchant" button before you're redirected to your return URL if the transaction is a guest payment.
You could optionally change the wording of the "Return to merchant" button by passing the 'cbt' parameter.
E.g.
    `<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Click here to complete your purchase">`

Unfortunately it's not possible to get guest checkouts automatically redirected to your return URL with Website Payments Standard.

If this is a must for you, you would need to integrate PayPal Express Checkout (free) which *always* redirects back to your site, since your site is the one 'calling the final sets' (calling the API call which completes the transaction. Namely, DoExpressCheckoutPayment).

Comment: The wording of HTML variables is confusing. You'd think it actually returns the customer back, but it just provides a link with the return URL on the Paypal page. Another thing that one can try is enable "Auto Return" in account settings. I am not sure if you can pass back variables to the return page this way.

Comment: Yes, if you turn on "Auto Return" it will automatically redirect to the `return` URL specified in the button. But you're right, in the "paypal account optional" flow it won't autoreturn as specified on Paypal website.

Answer (score 0):

When I see problems like this, the first thing I check is the URL that is being passed in the request.

Are you running your application locally? Are you passing a localhost URL to PayPal?

Are you passing a valid URL to PayPal?

Comment: true but i make sure these things before posting my question and when i pay with **Pay from PayPal account** (sandbox buyer account) i am directed to my return URL provided page easily. so the issue is there......